# Find a group $G$ which contains the elements $a,b,c$ such that $a\ne b$ and $ac=cb$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The title says it all. I'm trying to find a group $G$ which contains the elements $a,b,c$ such that $a\ne b$ and $ac=cb$.

I didn't have an idea how to construct the group $G$ in a smart way so I was looking for an example in $Z_5^*,Z_7^*, S_3, S_4$ and I couldn't find anything. Anyone has an idea how to start the construction of such a group based on the limitations above?

Thanks

Comment: There are examples in $S_3$, so look again! More generally, there are examples in any nonabelain group: just find two elements $a$ and $c$ that do not commute with each other, and let $b = c^{-1}ac$.

Comment: Very helpful comment. Thank you! @DerekHolt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not $S_3$? Note that
$$
\sigma \tau = \tau \sigma^2
$$
where $\sigma^3 = \tau^2 = \sigma \tau \sigma \tau = e$.

More generally, you can find an example in **any** non-abelian group.